# Drag and drop outlook selected attachtment with powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, attachment

I've managed to get all attachment from a mail and save it to a location.
Now i am trying to to drag and drop it to a listbox.
Now it gets all the attachements, but i want only the selecte on in the outlook message.

```
$outlook = New-Object -comobject outlook.application
$sel=$outlook.ActiveExplorer().selection 
    foreach ($s in $sel) {
      foreach ($at in $s.Attachments) 
        {if ($at.FileName -match 'SCAN_*') 
                 {$newname=[io.path]::ChangeExtension($Filesgo_listbox.SelectedItem,"PDF") 
                   if ($newname -NOTmatch "20*") {$newname= $DATUM + " " + $newname}
                   $name= join-path $curfil $newname }
            else {$name=join-path $curfil $at.FileName}
```

Comment: If you have the attachments already serialized on the file system, then they are no longer attachments, they are just files. Thus you need to select them from the file system. But you are not showing any code from your GUI, so, we cannot see what you are even doing. There are lots of examples all over the web showing drag and drop from the file system to a form. Just search for them.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing from my comment.

['PowerShell Drag & Drop files' winform](https://www.bing.com/search?q=%27PowerShell%20Drag%20%26%20Drop%20files%27%20winform&qs=n&form=QBRE&sp=-1&pq=%27powershell%20drag%20%26%20drop%20files%27%20winform&sc=0-38&sk=&cvid=4ABF9FBA84494A2888EB41748F0520E1)

```
# Example 1
Function DragDropSample() 
{
    [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")

    $form         = New-Object Windows.Forms.Form
    $form.text    = "Drag&Drop sample"
    $listBox      = New-Object Windows.Forms.ListBox
    $listBox.Dock = [System.Windows.Forms.DockStyle]::Fill

    $handler = {
        if ($_.Data.GetDataPresent([Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::FileDrop)) {
            foreach ($filename in $_.Data.GetData([Windows.Forms.DataFormats]::FileDrop)) {
                $listBox.Items.Add($filename)
            }
        }
    }
    $form.AllowDrop = $true
    $form.Add_DragEnter($handler)
    $form.Controls.Add($listBox)
    $form.ShowDialog()
}

DragDropSample | Out-Null
```

Similar Q&A right here on SP:

[PowerShell - DataGridView Windows Form Drag and Drop Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64297713/powershell-datagridview-windows-form-drag-and-drop-issue)